# Force the expansion of a macro parameter without \edef or \xdef

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

Two days I am looking for a solution but I have no more idea. This is my problem.

I'm trying to create a macro to automatically define new other macros to write references in a document. I want to create `\createrefmacro` which take one parameter (for example `Figure`). The `\createrefmacro` will create a new macro called `\refFigure` which will take one argument (the label of the reference) and an optional argument (I need an optional argument).

This is an MWE which should reproduce my problem (my original macro contains more details and the MWE may seem stupid!).

```
\documentclass{article}
  \makeatletter
  \def\createrefmacro#1{%
    \edef\macro{\csname ref#1\endcsname}%
    \edef\macro@i{\csname ref#1@i\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\gdef\macro{%
      \expandafter\@testopt\macro@i{}%
    }%
    \expandafter\gdef\macro@i[##1]##2{#1~\ref{##2}}%
  }
  \makeatother
  \createrefmacro{Figure}
  \createrefmacro{Table}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{First table}\label{tab1}
  \end{table}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \caption{First figure}\label{fig1}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \caption{Second figure}\label{fig2}
  \end{figure}
  \refFigure{fig1}\par
  \refTable{tab1}\par
  \refFigure{fig2}\par
\end{document}
```

With `\createrefmacro{Figure}` and `\createrefmacro{Table}`, I create the `\refFigure` and the `\refTable` macros. I write a small document with only 2 figures and 1 table then I try to insert corresponding references in the document. However, the result is not what I expect as can be seen below

[image]

I tried few tricks with no success:

1. Replace `\gdef` with `\xdef`:

   - In `\macro` but the compilation produce an error
   - In `\macro@i` but the problem still happens
2. Use (plenty of) `\expandafter` to force the expansion of `#1` in `\macro@i` but I don't really know how and where to use it in this particular case.

I know the existence of packages like `varioref` and the `\labelformat` macro which should do the job in a better way. However, I need a solution which does not use external packages because of submissions as a scientific article (and I'm also very curious of the solution of this tricky problem!).

Answer (score 13):

My first bet would be on

```
\newcommand\createrefmacro[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname ref#1\endcsname[2][]{#1~\ref{##2}}}
```

If I load `xpatch` for looking at the real meaning of `\refFigure` after

```
\createrefmacro{Figure}
```

I get the following answer:

```
> \\refFigure=\long macro:
[#1]#2->Figure~\ref {#2}.
```

that is exactly what you wish to obtain with the (non working) code you proposed. A working version would be

```
\makeatletter
\def\createrefmacro#1{%
  \expandafter\def\csname ref#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@testopt\csname ref#1@i\endcsname{}%
  }%
  \expandafter\def\csname ref#1@i\endcsname[##1]##2{#1~\ref{##2}}%
}
\makeatother
```

In this way `\createrefmacro` would first execute

```
 \expandafter\def\csname refFigure\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter\@testopt\csname refFigure@i\endcsname{}}
```

where the `\expandafter` at the end of the first `\csname...\endcsname` pair would trigger the formation of the token `\refFigure@i` and so this would bring you

```
\def\refFigure{\@testopt\refFigure@i{}}
```

Then

```
\expandafter\def\csname refFigure@i\endcsname[#1]#2{Figure~\ref{#2}}
```

would be equivalent to

```
\def\refFigure@i[#1]#2{Figure~\ref{#2}}
```

But the first solution is obviously cleaner.

### Analysis

Let's see where your code fails:

```
\def\createrefmacro#1{%
  \edef\macro{\csname ref#1\endcsname}%
  \edef\macro@i{\csname ref#1@i\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\gdef\macro{%
    \expandafter\@testopt\macro@i{}%
  }%
  \expandafter\gdef\macro@i[##1]##2{#1~\ref{##2}}%
}
```

First of all, `\gdef` is useless, as probably you won't issue `\createrefmacro` inside a group, but it does no harm. Assume that you give

```
\createrefmacro{Figure}
```

Then

```
\edef\macro{\csname refFigure\endcsname}
```

will be equivalent to

```
\def\macro{\refFigure}
```

(because `\refFigure` is still undefined, so it will be equivalent to `\relax` and stop expansion). Similarly

```
\edef\macro@i{\csname refFigure@i\endcsname}
```

will be the same as

```
\def\macro@i{\refFigure@i}
```

Now TeX will see

```
\expandafter\gdef\macro{\expandafter\@testopt\macro@i{}}
```

that would become

```
\gdef\refFigure{\expandafter\@testopt\macro@i{}}
```

and here is the main problem: the `\expandafter` will *not* come into action. So, with a subsequent `\createrefmacro{Table}`, the meaning of `\macro@i` would be `\refTable@i`! There is a possibility with `\expandafter`, let's look at it:

```
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\macro\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\@testopt\macro@i{}}
```

Can you see it? The first `\expandafter` will expand the third, thus the fourth, the fifth and the sixth, leaving

```
\expandafter\gdef\macro{\@testopt\refFigure@i{}}
```

which eventually becomes

```
\gdef\refFigure{\@testopt\refFigure@i{}}
```

as desired. The last job would become

```
\expandafter\gdef\macro@i[#1]#2{Figure~\ref{#2}}
```

(because `#1` is replaced by `Figure` and `##` becomes `#`), so this would do the correct

```
\gdef\refFigure@i[#1]#2{Figure~\ref{#2}}
```

Of course, what `#1` should do remains unexplained in your code (but you did say this). However, using directly `\csname...\endcsname` is much handier and doesn't require `\macro` and `\macro@i`.

Comment: Thank for you this fast answer. As I answer to David Carlisle, I will first try his cleaner solution. However, if I don't success, your answer will be very helpful to continue in finding a complete solution for my problem (and at least, understand a bit more TeX/LaTeX!).

Comment: I just read your second part (the analysis) and it is very helpful to understand my mistakes (very pedagogical). I think I still need to learn how to use `\expandafter`, this powerful and dangerous macro.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do with the default argument but this seems to work for your MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

  \def\createrefmacro#1{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname ref#1\endcsname[2][default]{#1~\ref{##2}}}


  \createrefmacro{Figure}
  \createrefmacro{Table}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htp]
    \caption{First table}\label{tab1}
  \end{table}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \caption{First figure}\label{fig1}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \caption{Second figure}\label{fig2}
  \end{figure}
  \refFigure{fig1}\par
  \refTable{tab1}\par
  \refFigure{fig2}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast answer. I first have macros defined like you propose but I changed them because of another problem. However, I made so many modifications since this old version... I will now try to clean my code and see if your solution can do the job.